# how to select all p not having align attribute and any other style options

Tags: html, css

how can I select all the p which is a child of article tag but not carrying any other attribute it.

you may check the picture please.
[image]

Comment: I did bro, sorry for the late response. I appreciate your work and help in the community.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
p:not([align]):not([style]) {
    background: red;
}
```

Should do the trick.